# Drupal - file_save_data -- > set type

Tags: file, drupal

How can i set the file type in drupal 7 for a file?
I want to create an uploaded file programmaticaly

```
$doc = file_get_contents($var["path"]);
$filename = basename($var["path"]);
$file = file_save_data($doc, 'public://'.$filename,FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

the following did not worked for me:

```
$file->type = 'text/xml';
file_save($file);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm...I think that this function is saving raw data, so you are responsible for file content, headers, extension and stuff. It's not like sending file over http protocol, where you can set file header.

Comment: Right!
But the function creates an managed file in drupal.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_data/7 says:
"Saves a file to the specified destination and creates a database entry"
So I should be able to set file type somehow.. 
In the admin/content/file admin page the TYPE is set to  'undefined'..

Comment: So Drupal is aware of the file. But that have nothing to do with file type, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Sorry, if i cant clear the point..
The file attribute "tpye" is set to undefined when its created programmaticaly. 
iam wondering why the file type cant not be set while using function file_save_data 
nore using file_save($file);

Answer (score 0):

When forcing the type this way, the string must match the machine name of a file type (cf. `admin/structure/file-types` to find the available file types) :

```
$file->type = 'document';
```

or

```
$file->type = 'video';
```

etc.

That being said, when you don't set the type and if you have installed the module [file_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity), it is automatically set to the first file type matching the MIME type of the file.

Reference :

```
/**
* Implements hook_file_presave().
*/
function file_entity_file_presave($file) {
  // Always ensure the filemime property is current.
  if (!empty($file->original) || empty($file->filemime)) {
    $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file->uri);
  }

  // The file type is used as a bundle key, and therefore, must not be NULL.
  // It defaults to FILE_TYPE_NONE when loaded via file_load(), but in case
  // file_save() is called on a new file object, default it here too.
  if (!isset($file->type)) {
    $file->type = FILE_TYPE_NONE;
  }

  // If the file isn't already assigned a real type, determine what type should
  // be assigned to it.
  if ($file->type === FILE_TYPE_NONE) {
    $type = file_get_type($file);
    if (isset($type)) {
      $file->type = $type;
    }
  }

  field_attach_presave('file', $file);

  // Fetch image dimensions.
  file_entity_metadata_fetch_image_dimensions($file);
}
```